# parsing substring from variable with ansible

Tags: regex, variables, ansible, substring, yaml

I have this snipplet:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  become: yes
  become_user: somesu
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      tmped: "{{varput | regex_search('(^(?:[^.]*.){4}([^.]*))')}}"

  - debug: msg="{{ tmped }}"

...
```

varput is

```
TEST123TEST.4.TES22TES.ZTER012UZT.20190910.555
```

and I want the debug to print out

```
20190910
```

However my regex print out

```
TEST123TEST.4.TES22TES.ZTER012UZT.20190910
```

any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already captured the necessary text into Group 1.

You can pass the second capturing group ID argument to `regex_search` to return the desired capturing group value:

```
tmped: "{{varput | regex_search('^(?:[^.]*\\.){4}([^.]*)','\\1') }}"
```

See the [`ansible` source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L149).

Answer (score 2):

Use split

```
tmped: "{{ varput.split('.')[-2] }}"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The string is 1) split to an array and 2) last but one element of the array is selected.